# pure javascript - creating my own fadeout function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a similar function to the jquery `.fadeOut()` effect in pure javascript, but I'm having trouble with my code. The error code:

> span[0].fadeOutEffect is not a function

My code:

```js
var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function fadeOutEffect() {
  var node = this
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!node.style.opacity) {
      node.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (node.style.opacity > 0) {
      node.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 50);
}

span[0].fadeOutEffect();
```

```html
<span>one </span><span>two </span><span>three </span>
```

Comment: You created a function but it's not magically going to become a property of every `<span>` element.

Comment: To elaborate on Pointy's comment, if you want to fade `span[0]`, you would probably want to add the element as a *parameter*, like `function fadeOutEffect(element) { ... }` and call it via `fadeOutEffect(span[0]);`.

Answer (score 1):

When I read your code, I see you likely want to add a function to the HTMLElement prototype  - it is not recommended but it will look like this:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.fadeOutEffect = function() {
  var node = this
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!node.style.opacity) {
      node.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (node.style.opacity > 0) {
      node.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 50);
}

var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");


span[0].fadeOutEffect();
```

```html
<span>one </span><span>two </span><span>three </span>
```

A cleaner way is passing the span:

```js
var fadeOutEffect = function(node) {
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!node.style.opacity) {
      node.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (node.style.opacity > 0) {
      node.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 50);
}

var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");


fadeOutEffect(span[0]);
```

```html
<span>one </span><span>two </span><span>three </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to call a function, on a DOM element, which doesn't exist. Try passing the element as a parameter to your function instead.

```js
var span = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function fadeOutEffect(node) {
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!node.style.opacity) {
      node.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (node.style.opacity > 0) {
      node.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 50);
}

fadeOutEffect(span[0]);
```

```html
<span>one </span><span>two </span><span>three </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a function as a property to the array of `span` elements. You should instead pass it as a parameter to the function you created. Also, `document.querySelectorAll("span");` returns an array of spans, as there can be multiple in your HTML document, so you can loop through each and apply you code to them.

See working example:

```js
function fadeOutEffect(nodes) {
  nodes.forEach(function(node) { // Loop through each node (each span) in the array of spans
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() { // Run your code
      if (!node.style.opacity) {
        node.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (node.style.opacity > 0) {
        node.style.opacity -= 0.1;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}

var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("span"); // Nodes is an array of spans
fadeOutEffect(nodes); // Pass the array of spans to your function
```

```html
<span>Hello world!</span>
```